# how many total displays can an ATI FireGL v3600 card drive?

Tags: graphics-card, display

Was digging around the office and found one of these:

[image]

I've noticed a lot of single head ATI cards supporting dual monitors via a DVI splitter as seen here:

[image]

On this particular V3600, there are two DVI dual link outputs.  Would it be possible to hook up two DVI splitters and run four monitors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each of the two dual-link outputs can provide a [maximum resolution](http://ati.amd.com/products/workstation/fireglmatrix.html) of 2560 x 1600, or about 4 megapixels. Unfortunately, I believe this is limited to a single (but high resolution) display, per output. Page 2 of [this PDF](http://www.amd.com/us/Documents/6830_ATI_Cadalyst.pdf) describes that two V3600 cards are required to support four 3D-accelerated monitors.

DVI splitters almost always mirror the output to two displays. An exception to this is that some video cards (particularly on Dell PCs) come with a [Low Force Helix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Force_Helix) connector and a special "splitter" cable, which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: For clarifications sake, some Dell PCs come with a standard (not a non-standard) connector which allows two monitors to be connected to a single output port. This is called the Low Force Helix connector which uses a DMS-59 connector on the cable which connects to it. This is not Dell specific, this is a standard used by other companies and this non proprietary / open standard that anyone can implement. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Force_Helix

Comment: @jetole Well spotted!